# Getting specfic value from a cell using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a table shown below, which has a header of "Status" and then the table data on the right hand side.
[image]

What I am trying to do is get the error value (in this case being 10). I have looked at the source
[image]

and tried to get the value using xpath, and also tried with find_element_by_name, but I cant seem to retrieve the value. Has anyone got any idea on how to get the value **10**

EDIT***

```
error = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="harvest-source-details"]/tbody/tr[12]/td/text()[2]')

error = browser.find_element_by_name('errors').text
print error
u''
```

Thanks.

Comment: "tried to get the value using xpath, and also tried with `find_element_by_name`" - show us your code please.

Comment: The `Errors: 10` is **not** inside this element (in other words, your code would have worked if the HTML was `<a name="errors">Errors: 10</a>`).

Comment: aaah, that makes sense, so whats the best way to retrieve the value if it is not inside the element?

Comment: Try to parse `browser.page_source` from `index=browser.page_source.find('<a name="errors">Errors: 10</a>')+len('<a name="errors">Errors: 10</a>')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as your xpath:

```
//a[@name='errors']/../following-sibling::text()
```